# Celery Group Task result is always None

Tags: celery, task

So this is my celery Tasks code where I am trying to group the results of a few tasks:

```
@tasks.task(name='tasks.sample_group')
def sample_group(self, **kwargs):
    tasks = [ add.s(**kwargs).set(queue = "vTestQueue")),
              sub.s(**kwargs).set(queue = "vTestQueue"))]
    return (group(tasks)).apply_async()

@tasks.task(name='tasks.add')
def add(**kwargs) : 
    print("add task started at " + str(datetime.now(tz=None))) 
    writefile("add" , kwargs['x'] + kwargs['y'])
    print("add task ended at " + str(datetime.now(tz=None))) 
    return kwargs['x'] + kwargs['y']

@tasks.task(name='tasks.subtract')
def subtract(**kwargs) :    
    print("subtract started task at " + str(datetime.now(tz=None))) 
    writefile("sub" , kwargs['x'] + kwargs['y'])
    print("subtract ended task at " + str(datetime.now(tz=None))) 
    return kwargs['x'] - kwargs['y']
```

The problem with the group is that it never returns the result of the operation. The result is always none. What do I need to set to get the result?

This is the config I am using:

```
accept_content = ["application/json"]
enable_utc = True
timezone = "Australia/Melbourne"
broker_url = "pyamqp://********************:8080/******"
result_backend = "rpc://"
```

Comment: So  the result None since I was trying to call the function sample_group remotely. If my client code creates a group and does a group_Result.get() I can see the group result.

Answer (score 0):

For Group you should use [GroupResult](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/canvas.html#group-results). Also do not try to call .get() inside a task as that is wrong way to do it.

Comment: In the docs I read doing a join() will get you all the results but it never works for me and I end up getting an error 'AsyncResult' object has no attribute 'join'. Any idea why that happens?

Comment: If you want to wait for all tasks in a Group to finish, then you should use Chord instead.